# ClojureScript Reagent Component Constantly Refreshed Resulting in Many POST Calls

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have been trying to fix this error for a while but it eludes me. The problem has something to do with the for loop because when I remove it the calls to the component are limited to one but with it it keeps being called. This results in infinite POST calls which I want to eliminate. In short the component keeps being rendered instead of just on loading the page.

```
(defn get-messages []
  "Gets the messages from the server"
  (let [response (r/atom "")]
    (fn []
      (POST "/get" {:handler #(reset! response %)})
      [:div
       (for [item @response]
         [:div
          [:h3.you (first item)] 
          [:p (second item)]])])))
```

I call it just like any other component:

```
(defn test []
 [:div
  [get-messages]])
```

The data that the post gets is simply

```
(["Bill" "What is the weather today?"] ["Jim" "The weather is warm"])
```

**EDIT**

I realised the error I was having had nothing to do with the lazy seq. Sorry for being unclear but the error was with rendering an object with a POST in it. The AJAX is called constantly. To fix it I included:

```
(:require-macros [cljs.core.async.macros :as cam])


 [clojure.core.async :as ac]
```

Then I used this surrounding the POST:

```
(cam/go
  (<! (ac/timeout 500))
  (POST "/ajax/get-message" {:handler #(reset! response %)}))
```

Thanks everyone for their patience.

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to address, given the context presented:

`for` returns a lazy sequence.  You probably want the result to be a vector, so try this:

```
(POST "/get" {:handler #(reset! response %)})
(into [:div]
  (vec (for [item @response]
         [:div
          [:h3 (first item)]
          [:p (second item)]])))
....
```

That will yield the following structure, which is what you want (pprinted from above code):

```
[:div
 [:div [:h3 "Bill"] [:p "What is the weather today?"]]
 [:div [:h3 "Jim"] [:p "The weather is warm"]]]
```

I'm not sure if this is the problem or not, but it's a good first step.

Second -- your spacing is not correct in many places, which can lead to subtle bugs involving mismatched parens, which could lead to a loop not behaving the way you expect.  In your last line, `]]]]` should be `]])]`, thus `for` is not being closed, for example.  As other examples, you indent `[:div` after the `POST` line, when it should not be indented, and you are using one space for all indentations, and it should be two except for the nested vectors.

Comment: The spacing is mostly because I struggle to input it in Stackoverflow with proper indentation. I'll try the vec.

Comment: @phlie very understandable, but it is important if you want others to be able to read your code -- my biggest question regarding this was that you do not seem to close the `for` loop on the last line (you have 9 left parens in your code, and only 8 right parens) ... don't know if this was a copy/paste error, but ...

Comment: @phlie After looking at the code again, I realized I had made an error and have modified it above.  Previously the result was a double-nested vector, when you want the flatter structure above, I think.  Please verify that the output above has the structure you want, which I think it does -- if so, the code above it is now correct.

Comment: I edited the spacing. Thanks. The code seems to work but it still gets called too many times so I'm going to set a timeout for it.

Comment: I realised the error and fixed it and edited my post. Thanks for the help.